# How to replace blank lines with character/strings with sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am trying to replace all my blank lines in a txt file with tags, so for example I have:

```
aaaaa

bbbbb

ccccc
```

and I want

```
<a>aaaaa</a><a>bbbbb</a><a>ccccc</a>
```

I have tried

```
sed 's/^\s*$/</a><a>/‘ file.txt
```

but it does not run, what instead should I do? thanks!

Comment: You have to use different delimiters. Since your replace string is also having `/`. Say: `sed 's@^\s*$@</a><a>@' file`

Comment: it works! thanks so much.

Comment: Use pipe as separator '|'. It is impossible for sed to know that '/' in "</a>" is not the argument separator. Also, the pattern you are looking for is 's|^\s*\n(\w+)\n\s*\n|<a>\1</a>|g'. Another thing is that you need multiline support. Not sure if your sed can do that. See "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264344/how-to-replace-a-multi-line-code-with-sed"

Comment: You're not just replacing blank lines, you're also adding tags to the start and end of the file (where there probably aren't any blank lines). Also, what do you want to do with consecutive non-empty lines?

Answer (score 1):

I have used below `awk` command and it's working as expected.

```
awk 'NF{printf "<a>" "%s",$0 "</a>"} END {print ""}' test.txt
```

**Output :**

```
<a>aaa</a><a>bbbbb</a><a>ccccc</a>
```